# Optgroups in a datalist

Tags: html, html-datalist, optgroup

I am trying to create a input-box where the available anwsers ar listed in a list below. This I can do but i am not able to sort the available anwsers in optgroups. When the code runs the anwsers is listed without the optgroups.
Is it at all possible to use optgroups in datalists or is optgroups exclusive to select elements?

Here is a code sample where the optgroups is not shown

```
<label>Välj en elbil
<input class="downdrop" id="valdModellCompare2" list="elfordon" onchange=getSelectValue();></label>
<datalist id="elfordon">
   <optgroup value="Elbilar">elbil
      <option value="teslas">Tesla Model S</option>
      <option value="teslax">Tesla Model X</option>
      <option value="tesla3">Tesla Model 3</option>
      <option value="i3">BMW i3</option>
      <option value="id3">Volkswagen ID.3</option>
      <option value="id4">Volkswagen ID.4</option>
      <option value="niro">KIA Niro</option>    
      <option value="etron">Audi e-Tron</option>
      <option value="polestar">Polestar 2</option>
      <option value="xc40e">Volvo XC40 Recharge</option>
      <option value="leaf">Nissan Leaf</option>
      <option value="taycan">Porsche Taycan</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup value="Plug-in Hybrider">hybrid
      <option value="outlander">Mitsubitshi Outlander Hybrid</option>
      <option value="v60hybrid">Volvo V60 twin engine</option>
      <option value="optima">KIA Optima SV</option>
      <option value="passatgte">Volkswagen Passat GTE</option>
      <option value="priushybrid">Toyota Prius Hybrid</option>
      <option value="golfgte">Volkswagen Golf GTE</option>
      <option value="x545e">BMW X5 45e</option>
      <option value="530e">BMW 530e</option>
   </optgroup>

</datalist>
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) doesn't indicate any support for `<optgroup>` elements within a `<datalist>`.

Answer (score 1):

While `optgroups` is exclusively a child of `select`, `select` can be a child of `datalist`!

Although it is not the cleanest solution, you can use a trick used for compatibility of browsers that don't support `datalist` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element

> In the more elaborate case, the datalist element can be given contents that are to be displayed for down-level clients that don't support datalist. In this case, the option elements are provided inside a select element inside the datalist element.

With the addition of `value="" readonly` to an `option` displaying the `optgroup` name. So that it is not possbile to select it.

```html
  <label>Välj en elbil
<input class="downdrop" id="valdModellCompare2" list="elfordon" onchange=getSelectValue();></label>

<datalist id="elfordon">
<label> Select from the list:
<select name="car">
   <optgroup value="Elbilar">elbil
      <option value="" readonly>Elbilar</option>
      <option value="teslas"> >Tesla Model S</option>
      <option value="teslax"> >Tesla Model X</option>
      <option value="tesla3"> >Tesla Model 3</option>
      <option value="i3"> >BMW i3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup value="Plug-in Hybrider">hybrid
      <option value="" readonly>Plug-in Hybrider</option>
      <option value="outlander"> >Mitsubitshi Outlander Hybrid</option>
      <option value="v60hybrid"> >Volvo V60 twin engine</option>
      <option value="optima"> >KIA Optima SV</option>
   </optgroup>
   </select>
 </label>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) says for `<optgroup>` :

> Permitted parents:    A `<select>` element.

There are no other elements mentioned as permitted parents. Therefore `optgroup` is exclusively a child of `select`.